# No shell log-in prompt in Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04, server, startup

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server system. It was running fine till I had a power failure. When I restarted, I couldn't see the shell login prompt.

The start-up session is like this:

```
 .........

 Starting CUPS print spooler/server       [OK]
 Starting Samba Auto-reload Integration   [OK]
 Stopping Samba Auto-reload Integration   [OK]
```

Then, it got stuck. I couldn't see the log in prompt. I can log in through `ssh` from a another computer though.

Comment: Are you saying you can't see the GUI login? If you downloaded ubuntu server, it's a headless install so there is no GUI

Comment: Igor, I am not interested in GUI login.   I couldn't see the shell log in. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried interactive boot? Not sure if it's available by default in Ubuntu, but it's saved me numerous times on Gentoo. Have you tried ctrl-alt-f2?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by the following command.

```
sudo pico /etc/default/grub
```

Change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”text”
```

this makes Ubuntu boot directly into Text Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (on 14.04.3 LTS server), make sure that the grub configuration is updated by running the following after editing /etc/default/grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.